# CWAC-EndlessAdpater with a dynamic LinearLayout per row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-adapter, cwac-endless

I have implemented the EndlessAdapter from [commonsware](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), at the moment I have only an EditText in a row.

But what I need and what I am trying to implement is a dynamic LinearLayout holding a various number of elements. One line of the LinearLayout should hold a description on the left side an a value for this description on the right side.

The EndlessAdapter and the list is already working properly, but I don't know where and how I should implement the dynamic LinearLayout inside the adapter and how I can pass through the data I want to insert (I have stored the description and values inside a ArrayList of a custom class).

Comment: This really has nothing to do with `EndlessAdapter`. If you temporarily remove `EndlessAdapter` from the setup, just putting your own custom adapter in your `ListView`, you should have the same questions. If you know how to set up your own custom adapter, then `EndlessAdapter` simply wraps around it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so I need to implement my custom solution into the getView method of my adapter and the getPendingView is not important for this approach, am I correct??

Comment: Correct. You need a pending view, but that's relatively independent of the complex rows that you are using for your main list body, which you would handle on your underlying adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your support, this quite helped me for getting the logic... I think I will implement a normal custom adapter and as soon as this works as expected I will wrap it with the EndlessAdapter... Tumbs up for CommonsWare